# Stuck in recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Going through Java Complete Reference I am stuck in Recursion. I print the intermediate results to see the changes in the value.I can see that the value of num will decrement up-to 1 and return 1, after that how the value of num is incrementing to 3 and 4? Any help?

```
class Recursion {

    public  int fact(int num){
        int result;

        if(num==1){
            return 1;
        }

        System.out.println("Befor fact value of num is: "+num);//here ok!
        result=fact(num-1)*num;
        System.out.println("After value of num is: "+num); //here not ok!
        //System.out.println("result= "+result);
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Recursion obj=new Recursion();
        System.out.println(obj.fact(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO the quickest way to "get" recursion is to play computer: write down each step, using paper and pencil. Write down the values. Write down the conditions.

Comment: They aren't *incrementing*. The values you are seeing as incrementing is actually where the recursion is unwinding. Take a paper and pencil and try and trace the code as an exercise. Write down each function call and the values being passed. Then it should become more clear.

Comment: Your code seems OK, it prints 24 that is fact(4). What's wrong ?

Comment: @mpromonet:I know my code is ok.I want to understand the flow of the program.

Comment: If you expand fact(num-1) with the fact method, everything becomes  clear.

Comment: @mpromonet:I think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call a fact method, Java will save that invocation in the stack, also it will save the value of the `num` variable, because its a local variable for fact method.

Since you didn't changed the `num` value then what happened will be like:

```
call fact(4) > print: Befor fact value of n is: 4
Then call fact(3) > print: Befor fact value of n is: 3
Then call fact(2) > print: Befor fact value of n is: 2
```

and since the Stack first in last out then what happened will be like:

```
continue with call of fact(2) > print: After value of n is: 2
Then continue with call of fact(3) > print: After value of n is: 3
Then continue with first call of fact(4) > print: After value of n is: 4
```

Comment: :You explained pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be printing the wrong variable,

```
System.out.println("Before fact value of n is: "+num);//here ok!
result=fact(num-1)*num;
// You didn't change "num".
System.out.println("After value of n is: "+result); //result, not num.
//System.out.println("result= "+result);
return result;
```

Which prints

```
Before fact value of num is: 4
Before fact value of num is: 3
Before fact value of num is: 2
After value of num is: 2
After value of num is: 6
After value of num is: 24
24
```

Comment: :I print those values to see the intermediate results, actual result is being returned.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey Edited, but you should have tried it first.

Comment: :No offense! I just copy and paste my code and run it, it's working for me.I think you are missing something.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey What do you think I'm missing? Because I ran this code to get that output.

Comment: :Ok ! delete all the println statements and it's working. My point was to understand the flow of the program that's why i am printing those values.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey I don't understand what you're saying. I ran it with the println statements. I made these changes to your `fact` method, it worked beautifully.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50642/discussion-between-mr-pandey-and-elliott-frisch)

Comment: I have no idea why the down-vote. Boggle's the mind.